# To make paypal with recurring payments account options

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I need using paypal to make recurring payments monthly.

In WP StandardFAQ I read that paypal support recurring payments.
I have to create Subscribe that is basicly clear.
I created account at paypal.com http://s52.radikal.ru/i136/1306/89/57fb61ab3c61.png with option "My Business Setup", 
by clicking on which I create "Subscribe" button and generated code insert ed in my site.
Clicking on this "Subscribe" button paypal.com is opened for paypal account.

But I want to create Sandbox site for testing of ste.
I created account at sandbox.paypal.com, but in my account option "My Business Setup",
http://s56.radikal.ru/i153/1306/47/fbca7c9f7848.png
Can I to I create "Subscribe" button in Sandbox? have I some wrong options in my account?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Subscription button in the Sandbox. How did you create your Sandbox account? Did you just go through the setup process on Sandbox.PayPal.com? If you did, you shouldn't. You should be using the Developer.PayPal.com site to create test accounts.

Signing up for Developer.PayPal.com is free and an account will be created for you automatically that you can use to create a Subscription button.